# Mapbox draw a polygon default colour

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, polygon

Does anyone know how to change the default colour for the drawn polygon using this example on Mapbox....https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

The light blue colour isn't showing up well on my maps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the documentation for changing the style: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/docs/API.md#styling-draw and examples: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/docs/EXAMPLES.md

You can add styles options with your other options for the Draw control. Using the setup in the example you linked and the example styles for lines and polygons:

```
    const draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    // Select which mapbox-gl-draw control buttons to add to the map.
    controls: {
        polygon: true,
        trash: true
    },
    // Set mapbox-gl-draw to draw by default.
    // The user does not have to click the polygon control button first.
    defaultMode: 'draw_polygon',
    styles: [
      // ACTIVE (being drawn)
      // line stroke
      {
          "id": "gl-draw-line",
          "type": "line",
          "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "LineString"], ["==", "active", "true"]],
          "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round"
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#D20C0C",
            "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
            "line-width": 2
          }
      },
      // polygon fill
      {
        "id": "gl-draw-polygon-fill",
        "type": "fill",
        "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["==", "active", "true"]],
        "paint": {
          "fill-color": "#D20C0C",
          "fill-outline-color": "#D20C0C",
          "fill-opacity": 0.1
        }
      },
      // polygon mid points
      {
      'id': 'gl-draw-polygon-midpoint',
      'type': 'circle',
      'filter': ['all',
        ['==', '$type', 'Point'],
        ['==', 'meta', 'midpoint']],
      'paint': {
        'circle-radius': 3,
        'circle-color': '#fbb03b'
        },
      },
      // polygon outline stroke
      // This doesn't style the first edge of the polygon, which uses the line stroke styling instead
      {
        "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-active",
        "type": "line",
        "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["==", "active", "true"]],
        "layout": {
          "line-cap": "round",
          "line-join": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
          "line-color": "#D20C0C",
          "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
          "line-width": 2
        }
      },
      // vertex point halos
      {
        "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-halo-active",
        "type": "circle",
        "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"],],
        "paint": {
          "circle-radius": 5,
          "circle-color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      // vertex points
      {
        "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active",
        "type": "circle",
        "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"],],
        "paint": {
          "circle-radius": 3,
          "circle-color": "#D20C0C",
        }
      },

      // INACTIVE
      // line stroke
      {
          "id": "gl-draw-line-inactive",
          "type": "line",
          "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "LineString"], ["==", "active", "false"]],
          "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round"
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#000",
            "line-width": 3
          }
      },
      // polygon fill
      {
        "id": "gl-draw-polygon-fill-inactive",
        "type": "fill",
        "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["==", "active", "false"]],
        "paint": {
          "fill-color": "#000",
          "fill-outline-color": "#000",
          "fill-opacity": 0.1
        }
      },
      // polygon outline
      {
        "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-inactive",
        "type": "line",
        "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["==", "active", "false"]],
        "layout": {
          "line-cap": "round",
          "line-join": "round"
        },
        "paint": {
          "line-color": "#000",
          "line-width": 3
        }
      }
    ]
});
```